# Problem trying to host 2 wordpress websites on 1 DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, digital-ocean

## What I want to achieve :

- To have 2 different wordpress websites on 1 droplet. One of them should be served at **example.com** the other should be served at **subdomain.example.com**.

## What is the problem :

- The first website is being served at both **example.com** and **subdomain.example.com**

## What I did :

1. I first setup the first website using the 1 click wordpress install droplet and it worked. It was served at **example.com**
2. After that I decided to setup the other one following a tutorial
3. I went to Networking > Domain and made two A records that point to the same droplet like this :

**subdomain.example.com - 167.160.120.1**

**example.com - 167.160.120.1**

4. I SSH into the droplet and executed the following commands :

- Download a new copy of WordPress with the wget command

```
wget wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

- After that extract the files

```
unzip latest.zip
```

- Then move the files to the /var/www/ folder:

```
mv wordpress /var/www/subdomain.example.com
```

- Then set the owner of the file to the Apache2 user:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/subdomain.example.com
```

- After that copy the existing Apache config:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.example.com.conf
```

- Then enable the new site:

```
sudo a2ensite
```

- Run a configtest:

```
sudo apachectl -t
```

- If you get Syntax OK reload Apache:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

- Then create a new MySQL database and username. To create the database first access MySQL:

```
mysql
```

- Then run the following queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE wp_site;

CREATE USER 'wp_site'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_site.* TO 'wp_site'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and this should have done it but the first website is now being serverd both at **subdomain.example.com** and **example.com**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use multisite?

Comment: Oh wow. I didnt know that this thing was possible as I am kind of new to wordpress. I guess its a better option, yes. Thanks !